# Ruby hash with array values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Say I have a hash like this

```
{"k1"=>["v1"], "k2"=>["v2"], "k3"=>["v3"], "k4"=>["v4"]}
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"v2", "k3"=>"v3", "k4"=>"v4"}
```

Is there a simpler way to do it than this ugly `inject`?

```
h1 = {"k1"=>["v1"], "k2"=>["v2"], "k3"=>["v3"], "k4"=>["v4"]}
h2 = h1.inject({}){|h,v| h[v.first]=v.last.first; h}
```

Answer (score 8):

Somewhat less ugly than your "inject" solution:

```
h1 = {"k1"=>["v1"], "k2"=>["v2"], "k3"=>["v3"], "k4"=>["v4"]}
h2 = Hash[*h1.map.flatten]
h2 # => {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"v2", "k3"=>"v3", "k4"=>"v4"}
```

As @the Tin Man points out in a comment, if your value arrays might have more than one element then you'll need to do something slightly different for it to work as expected:

```
h2 = Hash[*h1.map{|k,v|[k,v[0]]}.flatten]
h2 # => {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"v2", "k3"=>"v3", "k4"=>"v4"}
```

Comment: It won't work if the value arrays have more than one element.

Comment: Only works in 1.8, where `map` returns an `Array`. In 1.9, you need `Hash[*h1.map.to_a.flatten]`, since `map` gives you an `Enumerator`. Otherwise, very cool.

Comment: Note that (fortunately) there is no need to flatten the array (that was necessary for old versions of Ruby). An array of pairs define a mapping: Hash[h1.map { |k,v| [k, v[0]] }]

Comment: @Amaden, @tokland: thanks for the tip!  I've been doing Ruby stuff for a long time and yet have never spent any time using Ruby 1.9...

Comment: @tokland, yes and you could avoid the array index by doing `Hash[h1.map{|k,(v)| [k, v]}]`

Comment: maerics: Hash[pairs] works already in Ruby 1.8.7. @nohat. Indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You could modify it in-place with a simple `each`:

```
h = {"k1"=>["v1"], "k2"=>["v2"], "k3"=>["v3"], "k4"=>["v4"]}
h.each { |k,v| h[k] = v[0] }
```

Or, if you want to make a copy, you can use a cleaner `inject` thusly:

```
flatter_h = h.inject({ }) { |x, (k,v)| x[k] = v[0]; x }
```

Or, if you have [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516) available (i.e. Rails or Ruby 1.9):

```
flatter_h = h.each_with_object({ }) { |(k,v), x| x[k] = v[0] }
```

Comment: @Ryan: You should have left your's up, it was reasonable solution if you wanted to leave the original alone.

Comment: Wait, we can mutate? Well damn :)

Comment: I like the `(k,v)` thing in your `inject` option and went one step further with `h.inject({}){|h,(k,(v))| h[k]=v; h}`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a somewhat more attractive use of `inject`. `Hash#merge` is your friend:

```
hash = {"k1"=>["v1"], "k2"=>["v2"], "k3"=>["v3"], "k4"=>["v4"]}
hash.inject({}) {|r,a| r.merge(a.first=>a.last.first)}
```

Comment: Using `|r,(k,v)|` would be even more attractive, I added a couple options with this notation to my answer.

Comment: @mu: Nice, I didn't know you could get at the key/value arguments that way.

Comment: @the Tin Man: destructuring hashes like that has worked for a long time. The oldest Ruby I have lying around is 1.8.6 and it works there, but I'm quite sure this already worked in earlier versions too.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> h = {"k1"=>["v1"], "k2"=>["v2"], "k3"=>["v3"], "k4"=>["v4"]}
>> Hash[h.map { |k, vs| [k, vs.first] }]
=> {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"v2", "k3"=>"v3", "k4"=>"v4"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining the `Hash[h.map { |k, v| [k, v.first] }]` syntax from @tokland's answer with the array destructuring syntax introduced in @mu's `h.inject({ }) { |x, (k,v)| x[k] = v[0]; x }`, I came up with what I think is the cleanest solution:

```
h1 = {"k1"=>["v1"], "k2"=>["v2"], "k3"=>["v3"], "k4"=>["v4"]}
h2 = Hash[h1.map{|k,(v)| [k, v]}]
```